# Using mono attribute in inductive_set

Tags: isabelle

I'm struggling to prove that my `inductive_set` satisfies the necessary monotonicity requirement. Could somebody advise on what I'm doing wrong here?

```ml
theory Scratch imports Main begin

consts foo :: "'a set ⇒ 'a set"

lemma foo_mono [mono]:
 "x ⊆ y ⟶ foo x ⊆ foo y"
sorry

inductive_set blah :: "'a set"
where
  "x ∈ foo blah ⟹ x ∈ blah"
monos foo_mono

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you state your monotonicity lemma like this:

```
lemma foo_mono [mono_set]:
 "A ⊆ B ⟹ x ∈ foo A ⟶ x ∈ foo B"
```

Also note that you should use the `mono_set` attribute instead of `mono`, if you want the lemma to be used automatically by `inductive_set`. That is, using `mono_set` makes the `monos` clause on the `inductive_set` command unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that's super. A related followup: if I now instantiate my `'a` to its actual type of `nat × nat`, the monotonicity proof fails again! Do I need to include some theorem about the monotonicity of `(_,_)`?